# how to get the right icon in Android Launcher?

Tags: android, android-launcher

My Application is a Launcher, I have probleme to get the good size of icon, i tried to use the list of icon and to set the right size. but with devices that have an xxhdpi, my application carsh. the Class used to get Application information

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Formatter.BigDecimalLayoutForm;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PaintFlagsDrawFilter;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.PaintDrawable;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Adapter used for providing the applications to show on the launcher's basic
 * view.
 * 
 */
public class GridViewAppInfoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Rect mOldBounds = new Rect();
    private List<ApplicationInfo> apps;
    private Context context;
    private static final String TAG = "GridViewAppInfoAdapter";
    private static int lowVal;
    private static int medVal;
    private static int highVal;
    private static int xhighVal;
    private static int xxhighVal;
    public static ArrayList<String> lApplication = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> AppList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public GridViewAppInfoAdapter(Context context, List<ApplicationInfo> apps) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.apps = apps;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Log.e("GridView", "getView");
        final ApplicationInfo info = apps.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
        }

        Drawable icon = info.icon;
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        if (!info.filtered) {
            final Resources resources = context.getResources();
            DisplayMetrics highmetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            highmetrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
            int width = (int) resources
                    .getDimension(android.R.dimen.app_icon_size);
            int height = (int) resources
                    .getDimension(android.R.dimen.app_icon_size);
            final int iconWidth = icon.getIntrinsicWidth();
            final int iconHeight = icon.getIntrinsicHeight();

            if (icon instanceof PaintDrawable) {
                PaintDrawable painter = (PaintDrawable) icon;
                painter.setIntrinsicWidth(width);
                painter.setIntrinsicHeight(height);

            }
            // if (width > 0 && height > 0
            // && (width < iconWidth || height < iconHeight))

            if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
                final float ratio = (float) iconWidth / iconHeight;
                if (iconWidth > iconHeight) {
                    height = (int) (width / ratio);
                } else if (iconHeight > iconWidth) {
                    width = (int) (height * ratio);
                }

                if ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {
                    lowVal = 65;
                    medVal = 90;
                    highaVal = 130;
                    xhighVal = 180;
                    xxhighVal = 280;
                } else if ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
                    lowVal = 36;
                    medVal = 48;
                    highVal = 72;
                    xhighVal = 96;
                    xxhighVal = 144;
                } else if ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) {

                    lowVal = 36;
                    medVal = 48;
                    highVal = 130;
                    xhighVal = 173;
                    xxhighVal = 600;
                } else if ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL) {
                }
                switch (highmetrics.densityDpi) {
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(lowVal,
                            lowVal));
                    height = lowVal;
                    width = lowVal;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(medVal,
                            medVal));
                    height = medVal;
                    width = medVal;

                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(
                            highVal, highVal));

                    height = highVal;
                    width = highVal;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(
                            xhighVal, xhighVal));

                    height = xhighVal;
                    width = xhighVal;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(
                            xxhighVal, xxhighVal));

                    height = xxhighVal;
                    width = xxhighVal;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

                }
                // System.gc();
                final Bitmap.Config c = icon.getOpacity() != PixelFormat.OPAQUE ? Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
                        : Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
                Bitmap thumb;
                try {
                    thumb = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, c);
                } catch (Error e) {
                    thumb = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
                            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
                }

                final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(thumb);
                canvas.setDrawFilter(new PaintFlagsDrawFilter(
                        Paint.DITHER_FLAG, 0));
                // Copy the old bounds to restore them later
                // If we were to do oldBounds = icon.getBounds(),
                // the call to setBounds() that follows would
                // change the same instance and we would lose the
                // old bounds
                mOldBounds.set(icon.getBounds());
                icon.setBounds(
                        context.getResources().getInteger(
                                R.integer.image_padding),
                        context.getResources().getInteger(
                                R.integer.image_padding), width, height);
                icon.draw(canvas);
                icon.setBounds(mOldBounds);
                icon = info.icon = new BitmapDrawable(thumb);
                info.filtered = true;

            }
        }

        final TextView textView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.label);
        textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, icon, null, null);
        textView.setText(info.title);
        textView.setLines(2);
        lApplication.add((info.title).toString());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // supprime les répétitions
        List apps2 = new ArrayList();
        Set set = new HashSet();
        for (Object item : apps) {
            if (!set.contains(item)) {
                apps2.add(item);
                set.add(item);
            }
        }
        // Log.e("apps", "/" + set.size());
        return set.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return apps.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public void setApps(List<ApplicationInfo> apps) {
        this.apps = apps;

        for (int i = 0; i < apps.size(); i++) {
            AppList.add(apps.get(i).title.toString());
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getApplicationList() {
        ArrayList<String> AppList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < apps.size(); i++) {
            AppList.add(apps.get(i).title.toString());
        }
        return AppList;

    }


}
```

I have a probleme of memory with XXHDPI the log is given below

4

```
: E/AndroidRuntime(11857): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 18:32:40.124: E/AndroidRuntime(11857): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
07-15 18:32:40.124: E/AndroidRuntime(11857):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
07-15 18:32:40.124: E/AndroidRuntime(11857):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:718)
07-15 18:32:40.124: E/AndroidRuntime(11857):  a
```

I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Please recycle your Bitmaps, use the following link. It will stop your application from getting crashed.
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Replace

thumb = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, c);

to

thumb = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourSelectedImage, h, w, true);
 and check.